# Logstash: how to install azureblob input plugin without running of heap memory

Tags: docker, logstash, logstash-configuration

I'm running Logstash in Docker on Ubuntu 22 host with 16 GB of RAM.

This is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  tls:
    profiles:
      - setup
    build:
      context: tls/
      args:
        ELASTIC_VERSION: ${ELASTIC_VERSION}
    user: root
    init: true
    volumes:
      - ./tls/entrypoint.sh:/entrypoint.sh:ro,Z
      - ./tls/instances.yml:/usr/share/elasticsearch/tls/instances.yml:ro,Z
      - ./tls/certs:/usr/share/elasticsearch/tls/certs:z

  setup:
    profiles:
      - setup
    build:
      context: setup/
      args:
        ELASTIC_VERSION: ${ELASTIC_VERSION}
    init: true
    volumes:
      - ./setup/entrypoint.sh:/entrypoint.sh:ro,Z
      - ./setup/lib.sh:/lib.sh:ro,Z
      - ./setup/roles:/roles:ro,Z
      - ./tls/certs/ca/ca.crt:/ca.crt:ro,z
    environment:
      ELASTIC_PASSWORD: ${ELASTIC_PASSWORD:-}
      LOGSTASH_INTERNAL_PASSWORD: ${LOGSTASH_INTERNAL_PASSWORD:-}
      KIBANA_SYSTEM_PASSWORD: ${KIBANA_SYSTEM_PASSWORD:-}
      METRICBEAT_INTERNAL_PASSWORD: ${METRICBEAT_INTERNAL_PASSWORD:-}
      FILEBEAT_INTERNAL_PASSWORD: ${FILEBEAT_INTERNAL_PASSWORD:-}
      HEARTBEAT_INTERNAL_PASSWORD: ${HEARTBEAT_INTERNAL_PASSWORD:-}
      MONITORING_INTERNAL_PASSWORD: ${MONITORING_INTERNAL_PASSWORD:-}
      BEATS_SYSTEM_PASSWORD: ${BEATS_SYSTEM_PASSWORD:-}
    networks:
      - elastic-poc
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch

  elasticsearch:
    build:
      context: elasticsearch/
      args:
        ELASTIC_VERSION: ${ELASTIC_VERSION}
    volumes:
      - ./elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml:ro,Z
      - elasticsearch:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data:Z
      - ./tls/certs/ca/ca.crt:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/ca.crt:ro,z
      - ./tls/certs/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.crt:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.crt:ro,z
      - ./tls/certs/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.key:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.key:ro,z
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
      - 9300:9300
    environment:
      node.name: elasticsearch
      ES_JAVA_OPTS: -Xms512m -Xmx512m
      ELASTIC_PASSWORD: ${ELASTIC_PASSWORD:-}
      discovery.type: single-node
    networks:
      - elastic-poc
    restart: unless-stopped

  logstash:
    build:
      context: logstash/
      args:
        ELASTIC_VERSION: ${ELASTIC_VERSION}
    volumes:
      - ./logstash/config/logstash.yml:/usr/share/logstash/config/logstash.yml:ro,Z
      - ./logstash/pipeline:/usr/share/logstash/pipeline:ro,Z
      - ./generated_logs:/logs
      - ./tls/certs/ca/ca.crt:/usr/share/logstash/config/ca.crt:ro,z

    command:  bash -c 'logstash-plugin install logstash-input-azureblob'

    mem_limit: 12000m

    ports:
      - 5044:5044
      - 50000:50000/tcp
      - 50000:50000/udp
      - 9600:9600
    environment:
      LS_JAVA_OPTS: -Xms256m -Xmx256m
      LOGSTASH_INTERNAL_PASSWORD: ${LOGSTASH_INTERNAL_PASSWORD:-}
    networks:
      - elastic-poc
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
    restart: unless-stopped

  logs-generator:
    profiles:
      - post
    build:
      context: ./logs_generator
    volumes:
      - ./generated_logs/csv:/app/csv
      - ./generated_logs/json:/app/json

networks:
  elastic-poc:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  elasticsearch:
```

Here is the error I am getting when docker attempts to execute the "install logstash-input-azureblob":

```
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       | Validating logstash-input-azureblob
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       | Resolving mixin dependencies
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       | Installing logstash-input-azureblob
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype keepalive@openssh.com reply 1
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       | java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       | Dumping heap to java_pid1.hprof ...
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       | Unable to create java_pid1.hprof: File exists
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       | Exception in thread "Ruby-0-Thread-3@Compact Index (rubygems.org) Worker #2: /usr/share/logstash/lib/pluginmanager/main.rb:18" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       | Exception in thread "Ruby-0-Thread-2@Compact Index (rubygems.org) Worker #1: /usr/share/logstash/lib/pluginmanager/main.rb:18" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       | warning: thread "Compact Index (rubygems.org) Worker #0 (Ruby-0-Thread-1@Compact Index (rubygems.org) Worker #0: /usr/share/logstash/lib/pluginmanager/main.rb:18)" terminated with exception (report_on_exception is true):warning: thread "Compact Index (rubygems.org) Worker #3 (Ruby-0-Thread-4@Compact Index (rubygems.org) Worker #3: /usr/share/logstash/lib/pluginmanager/main.rb:18)" terminated with exception (report_on_exception is true):
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       | 
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       | Exception in thread "Ruby-0-Thread-4@Compact Index (rubygems.org) Worker #3: /usr/share/logstash/lib/pluginmanager/main.rb:18" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Is this the proper plugin for Logstash to read from an Azure BLOB container?